# Let $p( z)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}.$ Prove that $p(\alpha) = 0$ if and only in $p(\bar{\alpha})=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Let $p( z)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}.$ Prove that $p(\alpha) = 0$ if and only in $p(\bar{\alpha})=0$.

I have just started a linear algebra class and I have no idea how to even start this problem.

Comment: Do you know the general form of a polynomial? By the way, you can learn the basics of typesetting mathematics [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @WillR Please do not remove the content of the question from the post - the body should contain the question, not the title.

Comment: Hint: $p(\bar{\alpha}) = \overline{p(\alpha)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $p(z)=a_{n}z^{n}+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}z+a_{0}$, where $a_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$. Then, note that we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p(\alpha)=0&\iff a_{n}\alpha^{n}+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}\alpha+a_{0}=0\\
&\iff\overline{a_{n}\alpha^{n}+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{1}\alpha+a_{0}}=0\\
&\iff\overline{a_{n}\alpha^{n}}+\overline{a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}}+\cdots+\overline{a_{1}\alpha}+\overline{a_{0}}=0\\
&\iff a_{n}\overline{\alpha}^{n}+a_{n-1}\overline{\alpha}^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}\overline{\alpha}+a_{0}=0\\
&\iff p(\overline{\alpha})=0,
\end{aligned}
$$

since for all complex $\beta,\gamma$ we have $\overline{\beta\gamma}=\overline{\beta}\overline{\gamma}$ and $\overline{\beta+\gamma}=\overline{\beta}+\overline{\gamma}$, and $\overline{r}=r$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the steps and the formulas for each of the steps!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number that is not real. And let $Q(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\overline\alpha)$. Clearly $Q(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients.

Suppose that there is a polynomial $R(x)$ with $R(\alpha)=0$. Then $Q(x)$ divides $R(x)$.

Otherwise we have $R(x)=P(x)Q(x)+S(x)$, where $S(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree at most $1$ with $S(\alpha)=0$, none exist, this is a contradiction.

Comment: This answer is "correct," in that it provides just as much information as is necessary for an elegant solution. However, to the intended audience, i.e., someone who doesn't know how to *start* on this problem, I'm not convinced that this answer is either clear or useful.

Answer (score 0):

write:
$$
f(\alpha) = \Re(f(\alpha))+i\Im(f(\alpha))
$$
when $f$ has a zero, both real and imaginary parts must be zero, ie $\Re(f(\alpha))=0$ and $\Im(f(\alpha))=0$

now notice that if $f$ has real coefficients then
$$
f(\bar \alpha)=\overline {f(\alpha)} =\Re(f(\alpha)) -i\Im(f(\alpha))
$$